# Is VMware Workstation 16 Player not available for macOS (as host OS)?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I'm not sure if it's ever been this case, but when I looked here just now: https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html

... I realized that it's only available for Windows and Linux. Not macOS.

Does this actually mean that VMware doesn't run on Macs? If so, is there any particular reason? Has it ever been different? Is this a recent change?

Comment: Always been this way, Fusion was the first VMware product for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

VMWare Workstation is, as you've discovered, a Windows/nix product.

The Mac equivalent is [VMWare Fusion](https://www.vmware.com/uk/products/fusion.html) - available in Pro & Player versions; fully-fledged paid or freeware, limited to individual use.

It can run pretty much any other OS, same as the Workstation edition, but also macOS licensed VMs too.